# Why i cant upload .jsp files in glassfish server?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have an issue with uploading files to

```
Servlet/3.0 JSP/2.2 (GlassFish Java/Oracle Corporation/1.7)
```

When I try to upload files in .jsp with this contents :
[With this contents :](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/SecurityRiskAdvisors/cmd.jsp/master/cmd.jsp)

its tell me to download it , not to open it in server .

but when I upload an empty `.jsp` file its opened in a server, what is the problem ? is there any another alternative extensions for `.jsp` files ?

Comment: Does the API you are using to upload accept JSP files?

Comment: i dont understand , how do i know ?

Comment: How are you uploading the JSP files?

Comment: i have an upload script in site ,

Comment: its like this : /index.xhtml in url , and the body post req like this :
contents=contents&contents%3AtelPhone=&contents%3Amobile=&contents%3Aemail=&contents%3Aj_idt195_input=&contents%3Aj_idt198=&javax.faces.ViewState=6594100462661442029%3A4554530658055967207